# What's the idiomatic way to allow incoming connections on a TCP port, as of 2021?

Tags: debian, firewall, port, nftables, devuan

It's been years since I last fiddled with firewall rules; and I remember the iptables chains for input, forward and output, and their various rules. But the times, they have a-changed, and today iptables is a legacy interface. I'm hearing about nft, and ufw, and not quite finding my way.

What I *want* is pretty simple: For an application on my machine to be able to accept connections on some TCP port, say 5123. Naturally, I want this to persist over rebooting; and I want to use whatever mechanism other apps or services typically use.

What's the "right way", the idiomatic way, of doing this?

Assuming the answer is distribution-specific: I'm using Devuan Chimaera, i.e. Debian 11 without systemd.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using Debian 11, the recommended way would be indeed nftables. Nftables keeps its configuration in a single file:
/etc/nftables.conf which is then read on startup.

Debian ships configuration examples in `/usr/share/doc/nftables/examples/` you may find helpful.

External References you may find helpful as well:

- [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/nftables)
- [Nftables Wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/)
- [Nftables Wiki: 10 minute reference](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Quick_reference-nftables_in_10_minutes)

To answer your question straight:

```
# apt install nftables
# service nftables start
# nft add rule inet filter input tcp dport 5123 ct state new,established accept
```

It works fine as well without systemd, once nftables is activated in sysvinit or openrc.

Comment: `service nftables start` doesn't work on Devuan. Which means this isn't "started" automatically. Yet - the tables exist... Hmm. Anyway, I'll read the docs, so +1.

Comment: There's another issue here. `nft list ruleset` produces nothing, but `iptables-legacy-save` lists quite a few rules... which are not to be found in `/etc/nftables.conf`. So are you sure that's really what I need to be doing?

Comment: Oh, you have `iptables-legacy` installed and configured? While that's still a *possible and supported* way in Debian/Devuan 11, that is already a deviation from the "idiomatic way". You have to choose whether to update to the world of netfilter now, or later. You could use non-legacy `iptables` and `iptables-persistent` to keep using iptables-like syntax while the underlying mechanism changes to netfilter, or go all the way and decide how you want to manage netfilter rules in the future: manually (minimalist way) or using a frontend e.g. `firewalld` (RedHat-like) or `ufw` (Ubuntu-like).